# How to redirect bindings to "outside" of a XAML control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

Let's say I have a **ListView** with a **ContextMenu**. I'd like to use it as a separate control called **ListViewWithContextMenu**. How can I redirect the command bindings from ContextMenu so they're visible in **ListViewWithContextMenu**?

Example code:

**ListViewWithContextMenu.xaml**

```
<ListView x:Class="WpfApplication4.ListViewWithContextMenu"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ListViewWithContextMenu}}, Path= PreviewCommand}" />
    </ContextMenu>
</ListView.ContextMenu>
```

**ListViewWithContextMenu.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public partial class ListViewWithContextMenu
    {
        public ICommand PreviewCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(PreviewCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PreviewCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PreviewCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PreviewCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ListViewWithContextMenu));

        public ListViewWithContextMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext><local:MainWidnowViewModel></local:MainWidnowViewModel></Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
            <local:ListViewWithContextMenu PreviewCommand="{Binding Preview}"></local:ListViewWithContextMenu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public class MainWidnowViewModel
    {
        public MainWidnowViewModel()
        {
            Preview = new DelegateCommand(PreviewMethod);
        }

        private void PreviewMethod()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("PREVIEW");
        }

        public ICommand Preview { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This code does not call the PreviewMethod in ViewModel which I want to achive

Comment: I have a solution to your problem. Give me a moment to write it up as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, instead of creating your "ListViewWithDataContext" as a regular user control, create it as a WPF "CustomControl". For this, perform the following steps:

- Delete your existing "ListViewWithDataContext" control
- Right-click on your project and click "Add New Item" -> "Custom Control (WPF)".
  [image: Custom Control]
- Visual Studio will automatically create a new project folder "Themes" and create a new .xaml file called "Generic.xaml" underneath it, like so:

[image]

- Visual Studio will also create a straight-up C# class file titled, "ListViewWithContextMenu.cs"

**Copy and paste the following code from here into the corresponding files:**

Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4">


<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ListViewWithContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ListViewWithContextMenu}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    <Border.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem  Command="{TemplateBinding PreviewCommand}" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Border.ContextMenu>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

ListViewWithContextMenu:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication4
{

   public class ListViewWithContextMenu : ListView
   {

       public ICommand PreviewCommand
       {
           get { return (ICommand)GetValue(PreviewCommandProperty); }
           set { SetValue(PreviewCommandProperty, value); }
       }

       public static readonly DependencyProperty PreviewCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PreviewCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ListViewWithContextMenu));


       static ListViewWithContextMenu()
       {
           DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ListViewWithContextMenu), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ListViewWithContextMenu)));
       }
   }
}
```

I tested it, and it works.

[image: It works]

**What we did here:**
Since all we want to do is leverage the existing ListView control, but not change any of the existing UI appearances, we simply created a ListView  "CustomControl" that essentially overrides the current template. In the .cs file, we defined the PreviewCommand DependencyProperty.

In the Generic.xaml file, we used a "Border" as a root-level control to house the Control (although we could have used a Grid, or whatnot) and we added a context menu to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I'll test it tommorow :)

Comment: No problem! Hit me up if you have questions about the answer I provided.